# Hooked VirtualAlloc returns nullptr when called by system DLLs

Tags: c++, c, windows, memory, dll

I would like to track memory allocations done by `VirtualAlloc`. For that I tried to use [mhook](https://github.com/apriorit/mhook) and [easyhook](http://easyhook.github.io/index.html). Both work fine as long as I call `VirtualAlloc` myself. The registered hook is called, from there I call the real `VirtualAlloc` function and memory is returned as expected.

My problem now is that I try to open a [SFML](https://www.sfml-dev.org/)-window and the `VirtualAlloc` call in there is captured but no memory is returned. The function call goes through sfml-window-2.dll and from there it calls [wglCreateContext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/dd374379(v=vs.85).aspx) that calls CreateAnyContext which calls `VirtualAlloc`. `wglCreateContext` is in Opengl32.dll. I guess my userspace code doesn't have the permission to allocate memory for it. My question is, why is a system library going through the same stub (that I hooked) if I am not allowed to allocate memory for it? And how could I distingush these calls and prevent that from happening?

I mean, in my particular case I could wait until the window is open and hook `VirtualAlloc` after that. But this would be a really bad solution because I would like to track arbitrary programs maybe even inject my dll to track the memory.

**EDIT:**
I not only want to track the programs memory but I also want to be able to reset it to a recorded state, all while the programs execution should not be slowed down too much because in my case it will be games. Therefore I wanted to start with VirtualAlloc and set the `MEM_WRITE_WATCH` flag and track the pages returned by `GetWriteWatch` manually. I already wrote a vector that can be reset this way but I need it to be more general. **/EDIT**

Another thing to note is, that I have tried it with `HeapAlloc` which is called in said function too but it returns memory. This is the reason why I tried two libraries. 
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you displaying in a UI? wglCreateContext is for OpenGL init which interacts with the graphics device driver. It could be that the graphics device driver also hooks VirtualAlloc to pass perhaps additional values to it? I have noticed that the returned memory for a 200MB buffer needed for reasons unkown to me over 1s for page faults which is a staggering amount of CPU time. This was some years ago I did measure this.

Comment: Anyway there is no need to hook VirtualAlloc. Download the Windows Performance Toolkit, wpr -start VirtualAlloc, execute use case, wpr -stop c:\temp\VirtualAllocTracing.etl and view the data with WPA (the best ETW viewer) to find pretty much any leak: https://aloiskraus.wordpress.com/2017/12/13/the-case-of-ngen-exe-needing-50-gb-of-memory/

Comment: @AloisKraus Thank you for the interessting read. Yes, I open an OpenGL window. The function does not seem to be hooked, I followed a VirtualAlloc call of my own to the same address as the one being called from wglCreateContext. But I will track it again with that in mind. I updated my use case in my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that I wasn't allowed to alter the flags. My workaround, since I can't know who the caller is in a reasonable way, I allocate it with altered flags and if that fails I allocate it again with the original flags.